# Recover field Json 2 array level gson or Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have this Json and i can´t recover the field "entidad" and "oficina":

```
{
  "resultado": [
    {
      "columa": [
        "p"
      ],
      "datos": [
        {
          "row": [
            {
              "oficina": "0000",
              "entidad": "1234",
              "nombre": "nombre persona"
            }
          ],
          "meta": [
            {
              "id": 4700925,
              "type": "node",
              "deleted": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": [],
  "responseTime": 84
}
```

How can I recover the field "oficina" and "entidad"?
I could use Gson or Jackson.
I can´t recover this fields.

thank you

Comment: Json edited. Thanks @Flown.

Comment: What is your actual problem? What have you tried so far? Why can't you retrieve the fields?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried to get the filed. It will be useful to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Get your array 'row'. When you got it, you can iterate it and extract the elements:

Get resultado --> get datos --> get row, then:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayJSON.length; i++) {
   JSONObject objectJSON= arrayJSON.get(i);
   String entidad = objectJSON.getString("entidad");
   String oficina = objectJSON.getString("oficina");
}
```